# Append to each item in array using Javascript

Tags: javascript, arrays, foreach

I have a code in JavaScript and i would like to append "i" to each item of the array inside the object. here is the code. Could anyone go through it and fix this code

```
    const forArray = [
    {
      username: "john",
      team: "red",
      score: 5,
      items: ["ball", "book", "pen"]
    },
    {
      username: "becky",
      team: "blue",
      score: 10,
      items: ["tape", "backpack", "pen"]
    },
    {
      username: "susy",
      team: "red",
      score: 55,
      items: ["ball", "eraser", "pen"]
    },
    {
      username: "tyson",
      team: "green",
      score: 1,
      items: ["book", "pen"]
    },
  
  ];

    const itemsArray = [];
    forArray.forEach(item => {
      let{items} = item;
      items = items + "i";
      itemsArray.push(items);
  })
  console.log(itemsArray);
```

Answer (score 1):

Using [`map()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map)

```js
const forArray = [{username:"john",team:"red",score:5,items:["ball","book","pen"]},{username:"becky",team:"blue",score:10,items:["tape","backpack","pen"]},{username:"susy",team:"red",score:55,items:["ball","eraser","pen"]},{username:"tyson",team:"green",score:1,items:["book","pen"]}];

const itemsArray = forArray.map(profile => 
  profile.items.map(item => item + 'i').join(',')
)
console.log(itemsArray);
```

Comment: t does the job but i am looking to print out the result Array(4) 0: "balli ,booki ,peni" 1: "tapei ,backpacki ,peni" 2: "balli ,eraseri ,peni" 3: "booki ,peni" length: 4

Comment: can each group of items be on the same line ?

Answer (score 0):

Is this what you want? The code below will keep your original structure intact but append an i to the end of each element within the items array nested inside each object.

```
const forArray = [
    {
      username: "john",
      team: "red",
      score: 5,
      items: ["ball", "book", "pen"]
    },
    {
      username: "becky",
      team: "blue",
      score: 10,
      items: ["tape", "backpack", "pen"]
    },
    {
      username: "susy",
      team: "red",
      score: 55,
      items: ["ball", "eraser", "pen"]
    },
    {
      username: "tyson",
      team: "green",
      score: 1,
      items: ["book", "pen"]
    },
  
  ];

  forArray.map(item => item.items = item.items.map(i => i += 'i'));
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use Map and append `i` to each element in the array and then use `flat()`to flatten the arrays

```js
const forArray = [ { username: "john", team: "red", score: 5, items: ["ball", "book", "pen"] }, { username: "becky", team: "blue", score: 10, items: ["tape", "backpack", "pen"] }, { username: "susy", team: "red", score: 55, items: ["ball", "eraser", "pen"] }, { username: "tyson", team: "green", score: 1, items: ["book", "pen"] }, ];

    const itemsArray = [];
    forArray.forEach(item => {
      let{items} = item;
      itemsArray.push(items.map(o=>o+"i"))
  })
  console.log(itemsArray);
```

Comment: it does the job but i am looking to print out the result Array(4)
0: "balli ,booki ,peni"
1: "tapei ,backpacki ,peni"
2: "balli ,eraseri ,peni"
3: "booki ,peni"
length: 4